# Baffling Sudden Error on loading data table

Tags: wpf, vb.net, ado.net

I'm using VB.net and WPF 4, as well as an SQL database.

I have been using this EXACT code successfully for several days now, with absolutely no problems whatsoever. However, now, suddenly, it is throwing the weirdest exception...

```
Public Class ROSTER
   Dim table_adapter As New AGENT_ROSTERTableAdapters.AGENTROSTERTableAdapter
   Dim roster_table As New AGENT_ROSTER.AGENT_ROSTERDataTable
...
```

I have not deleted anything relating to this, and I can still do things similar to this, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why I am getting the following error:

> XamlParseException occured
>   'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '106'.

On detail, every field contains the following:

> {Cannot evaluate expression because we are stopped in a place where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code of the current method may be optimized.}

Why is this doing this, and what can I do to fix it??

Comment: Are you aware of the spelling error in your posted code?  Can we assume that that is not the problem?

Comment: On "Dim table_adaptor" and "AGENT-ROSTER", yes. If you're seeing something I'm not, then it may be the problem. Anyway, I'm going to fix those two.

Comment: Hmm...it appears I'm getting that every single time I try and declare something like "Dim WINDOW As New Window" "Window.Show()" Is my Type Converter broken or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! This particular error is caused by my debugger having a bug in itself. To fix it, I will have to reinstall Visual Studio Express 2010, etc. Meanwhile, I have another computer I can work on my project on.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that the exception is a **XamlParseException** hence should not have anything to do with the code you posted? (If that code is used for the parsing then that's my mistake, it would however be helpful if you could provide more context)

Comment: Hmm, I'm away from the code for a while, but I can give you some "verbal" context. First of all, no, the code is not used for parsing. Basically, this code is at the top of my window's class (ROSTER), and everything below it just declared variables and works with the window and the datatable and dataadapter.

Answer (score 0):

A `XamlParseException` is thrown whenever any exception is encountered while parsing XAML.  The message tells you that `TypeConverterMarkupExtension` is what threw the exception, so you need to take a look at the places in your XAML where you're using type converters.  Looking at the stack trace in the inner exception will help you there.

Comment: Last time I checked, the inner exception was something about "cannot recognize image type", which doesn't make sense, because I didn't ask for an image (and this code worked before)

Comment: Check the *stack trace* on the inner exception.  That will tell you what line of code is throwing the exception.  That gives you something you can debug.